# workbench color customization in vscode not taking any effect in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, colors, settings

I adjusted the colors for the terminal in visual studio code in settings.json but they are not taking any effect as you see in the screenshot below. Could anyone help me with how to fix this?

[screenshot of my vscode with terminal opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4inM.png)

These are the complete settings I have in the settings.json file:
`{ "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern", "editor.wordWrap": "on", "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off", "workbench.sideBar.location": "right", "editor.formatOnType": true, "editor.linkedEditing": true, "workbench.colorCustomizations": { "terminal.foreground": "#eff0eb", "terminal.ansiBlack": "#282a36", "terminal.ansiRed": "#ff5c57", "terminal.ansiGreen": "#5af78e", "terminal.ansiYellow": "#f3f99d", "terminal.ansiBlue": "#57c7ff", "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#ff6ac1", "terminal.ansiCyan": "#9aedfe", "terminal.ansiWhite": "#f1f1f0", "terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#686868", "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#ff5c57", "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#5af78e", "terminal.ansiBrightYellow": "#f3f99d", "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#57c7ff", "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta": "#ff6ac1", "terminal.ansiBrightCyan": "#9aedfe", "terminal.ansiBrightWhite": "#eff0eb", }, "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [ ], "workbench.settings.editor": "json", "window.zoomLevel": 1, }`

I tried setting it for both 'user' and 'workspace', setting the option 'Determines which settings editor to use by default.' to json. This also didnt't work.

I tried restarting the terminal and restarting vscode completely, didn't work.

Comment: your terminal seems to have no highlighting at all. try printing some text with colour ansi escape codes or adjust your prompt config to make it colourful and then come back with more info.